# Best Virtual Machine for OpenGL, IE Testing, Small Footprint?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'm looking for a good virtual machine server to use on a WinXP32 host.  I've used VirtualBox, VirtualPC, and VMWare in the past, but I'm out of date with what they currently support.  These are my use cases, not sure if some of them are possible:

- I develop a game engine for fun.  It would be nice to be able to test it on Win7, Linux, or even Mac without having to go to another machine or reboot.  So if OpenGL hardware is exposed inside the machine interface, this is a big plus.  If I can emulate a 64-bit OS on my 32-bit host, it's another big win.
- I do web development and it would be good to test other versions of IE.
- It seems that some virtual machines always leave processes/services running and add extra devices.  The less of this, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some info on the 64 bit question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124/can-i-run-a-64-bit-vmware-image-on-a-32-bit-machine

I suspected that 32 couldn't run true 64 bit.

I would go with virtual box or virtual pc for your IE testing.  More full featured compared to the vmware player.

As for things continuing to run after a VM has been shut down, I haven't experienced that.

Comment: I tried out VirtualBox and have been pretty pleased with it.  It offers D3D and OpenGL acceleration, but I haven't tried them out yet.  I was even able to installe Ubuntu x64 using my 32-bit host--very nice.  It did install a network adapter in device manager and another network connection, but it was optional in the install process, so maybe it would work without them?